# Unsigned char overflow with subtraction

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to work out how unsigned overflow works with subtraction, so I wrote the following test to try it out:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

unsigned char minWrap(unsigned char a, unsigned char b) {
    return a > b ? a - b : a + (0xff - b) + 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned char a = 0x01, b = 0xff;
    unsigned char c = a - b;

    printf("0x%02x 0x%02x 0x%02x\n", a-b, c, minWrap(a,b));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Which gave as output:

```
0xffffff02 0x02 0x02
```

I would have expected the output to be the same three times. My question is: is it always safe to add/subtract unsigned chars and expect them to wrap around at `0xff`?

Or more general, is it safe to compute with `uintN_t` and expect the result to be modulo 2^N?

Comment: Language lawyer: unsigned types don't overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it always safe to add/subtract unsigned chars and expect them to wrap around at 0xff?

No.  In C, objects of type `char` go through the *usual integer promotions*.  So if the range of `char` fits in `int` (usual), it is converts to `int`, else `unsigned`.

`a - b` -->  `0x01 - 0xFF` --> `1 - 255` --> `-254`.

The below is undefined behavior as `%x` does not match an `int` and the value of -254 is not in the `unsigned` range (See [@EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613418/unsigned-char-overflow-with-subtraction/32614141#comment53079577_32614141) comment).  A typical  behavior is a conversion to `unsigned`

```
printf("0x%02x\n", a-b);
// 0xffffff02
```

---

> it safe to compute with `uintN_t` and expect the result to be modulo 2^N?

Yes.  But be sure to make the result of type `uintN_t` and avoid unexpected *usual integer promotions*.

```
#include <inttypes.h>

uint8_t a = 0x01, b = 0xff;
uint8_t diff = a - b;

printf("0x%02x\n", (unsigned) diff);
printf("0x%02" PRTx8 "\n", diff);
```

Comment: The `printf()` is only undefined behavior if the result of the subtraction is negative, since positive signed integers are guaranteed to have the same value as the corresponding unsigned type.

Comment: @EOF  Disagree.  "If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined" and "o,u,x,X The `unsigned int` argument is converted" §7.21.6.1 9 does not include a range exception.  Agree about `int` positive range fitting in `unsigned`, but the size of the 2 may differ.

Comment: C11 draft standard, `6.5.2.2 Function calls, Section 6` makes an explicit exemption:  `[...]the behavior is undefined, except for the following cases:
— one promoted type is a signed integer type, the other promoted type is the
corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;`

Comment: @EOF Agreed - answer amended.  LSNED

Answer (score 1):

`a-b` in the `printf` line is evaluated after `a` and `b` are promoted to `int`. Also, the value is being treated as an `unsigned int` due to the use of `%x` in the format specifier by your run time environment.

It's equivalent to:

```
int a1 = a;
int b1 = b;
int x = a1 - b1;
printf("0x%02x 0x%02x 0x%02x\n", x, c, minWrap(a,b));
```

Section **6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions** of the C99 standard has more details.

In theory use of an `int` when an `unsigned int` is expected in `printf` is cause for undefined behavior. A lenient run time environment, like you have, treats the `int` as an `unsigned int` and proceeds to print the value.

Comment: unless `(singned) int` cannot represent all values of `unsigned char`, the expression will return an `int`, not an `unsigned int`.

Comment: @EOF, do you mean "unless `unsigned int` can represent all values of `unsigned char`"? If not, I don't follow what you are saying.

Comment: @RSahu: If an `int` is wide enough that any `unsigned char` can be represented as a (positive) `int` -- normally the case -- then the usual arithmetic conversions will convert to `int` rather than `unsigned int`

Comment: No. C11 draft standard, `6.3.1 Arithmetic operands 6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers, Section 2 [...]If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int.`

Comment: @EOF. Thanks for the reference. It makes sense now. I corrected my answer.

Comment: The `%x` in the `printf()` doesn't affect the type of the expression used to calculate the argument. Indeed, if the result of the expression is a negative number, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @EOF, I see the following in the standard, "Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
until the value is in the range of the new type." Given that, why should the `printf` call result in undefined behavior when a negative number is used for the `%x` format specifier?

Comment: Read C11 draft standard, `6.5.2.2 Function calls`. Long story short, if the function either has no prototype, or is a variadic function (like `printf()`), the arguments need to match more precisely.

Comment: @EOF, Makes sense now. Thanks for your patience and helping me learn something new today.

Answer (score 1):

From 6.3.1.8/1 of the standard concerning integer conversions:

> The integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then the following rules are applied to the promoted operands
>
> If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is
>   needed.
>
> Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have
>   unsigned integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer
>   conversion rank is converted to the type of the operand with greater
>   rank.
>
> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
>   greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then
>   the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the
>   operand with unsigned integer type.
>
> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can
>   represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type, then the operand with unsigned integer type is converted
>   to the type of the operand with signed integer type.
>
> Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
>   corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

In this case, the wrap-around is well defined.  In the expression `a-b`, because both operands are of type `unsigned char`, they are first promoted to `int` and the operation is performed.  If this value was assigned to an `unsigned char`, it would be properly truncated.  However, you're passing this value to `printf` with a `%x` format specifier which expects an `unsigned int`.  To display it correctly, use `%hhx` which expects an `unsigned char`.

Comment: You cut of the important part right before your quote. `Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then the
following rules are applied to the promoted operands:[the part you quoted here]`.

Comment: @EOF  Thanks.  I updated the quote and made some corrections.

Comment: You skipped over section 6.3.1.1 (describing the integer promotions), which is the most important for this question -- the conversions in 6.3.1.8 are irrelevant as they don't apply (the second paragraph in your quote is always true)

Comment: I did not know about the `%hhx`. Thanks